# Replace specific characters in file contents using a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have the code below which reads the list of files and replaces the back and forward slashes in the file.

Requirements: I need to replaced characters to `-` (hyphen) if file contents are other than `- .0-9A-Za-z` (hyphen, space, dot, 0 to 9 , a to z and A to Z)

Note: if the bat file has syntax error then my data file is getting the empty. It should never happen.

Please help.

```
@echo off
Mode 85,35 & color 0A
Title Replace Multi String using Regex with vbscript into Folder with text files
Set "Source_Folder=\\server\Import\LoadError\dump"
Set "Backup_Folder=\\server\APImport\LoadError\dump\Backup_dump\"
Rem :: Just make a backup of folder and its contents if something went wrong!
If Not Exist "%Backup_Folder%" XCopy "%Source_Folder%" "%Backup_Folder%" /D /Y /E /F >%~dp0BackupLogFile.txt
Set "VBSFILE=%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" & Call :CreateVBS
Set "TmpFile=%Temp%\%~n0.tmp"

for /R "%Source_Folder%" %%f in (*JEG_OAP*.*) do (
    echo( ------------------------------------------
    echo  Replacing Contents of "%%f"


    echo( ------------------------------------------
    Call :Search_Replace "%%f" "%TmpFile%"
    Move /Y "%TmpFile%" "%%f">nul
)

Timeout /T 2 /NoBreak>nul & Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:CreateVBS
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Function Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = "%~1" 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo strPattern = "[\\\/\/`%''*+.:;<>=!_&~{}[]^?$#@"]"
    echo strReplace = "-"
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    echo strResult = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace^)
    echo Search_Replace = strResult
    echo End Function
)>"%VBSFILE%"
Exit /b 
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Search_Replace <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
Cscript //nologo "%VBSFILE%" < "%~1" > "%~2"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying the value for `str_Pattern`?

Comment: I wish people would stop writing batch files to create VBScript files to do the actual work. You can implement everything your script does with VBScript alone.

Comment: I tried str_Pattern by adding other other character it fails for all.

Comment: We'll edit your question to show us the code you've tried for the actual task and which failed to work as you had expected. You shouldn't post code which doesn't attempt the task and expect us to modify it for you.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers VBS is also quite ancient. PowerShell may be a better solution

Comment: then how write it

Comment: @phuclv it wasn’t the age of the technology that Ansgar was referring to, it’s the fact they are using one technology to wrap another when it’s quite capable of doing everything itself. The same would apply if someone was using a Batch file to wrap the creation and execution of a Powershell script for example.

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing:

```
    echo strPattern = "[\\\/\/`%''*+.:;<>=!_&~{}[]^?$#@"]"
```

with:

```
    echo strPattern = "[^-.0-9A-Za-z\n\r]"
```

This should pick out all characters which are not in the set, instead of trying to define each that you'd rather not have.

Comment: if my bat as some syntax error . my data files are getting empty. which will be a big problem

Comment: @Karun, that is not my issue. I didn't write any of the code you previously accepted as working, and I'm not going to rewrite the entire script, to satisfy something over which I have little control.